Remove virtual service account associated with a windows service
I use WiX to create an MSI installer that installs an application that runs as a Windows Service. The user that executes the service is a virtual service account (NT SERVICE\MyServiceUserName).
On some Windows versions, e.g. Windows 10 22H2, the virtual service account gets removed from the system, but related registry keys, e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\[SID of account name], and the user profile folder are not. Inside the user folder the OS still uses some resources and I think that's the reason why the folder cannot be deleted, even after a sytem restart.
That left obselete data produces side effects when installing the application again. Because the user profile folder is not deleted, the folder for the service user of the second installation sometimes is simply called TEMP (related registry keys in the ProfileList then exist, too). After a system restart, all data inside the TEMP folder is cleared, so the application data is lost...
As one workaround it helps to deinstall the application with its service, perform an OS restart and to delete the registry key and user folder manually. Then, after a new installation, all is fine from registry key and folder name perspective.
Second workaround is to disable the service, OS restart and use a Win32 API (DeleteProfile of userenv.dll) in a custom action to delete it. Then the installation sequence deinstalls the application and service and all is fine.
But what I need is a programatically way that ensures/forces that all virtual service account related stuff is cleared from the system when the service gets removed. All, for sure, without manual interaction. It is accepted, that the system automatically restarts.
Does anybody has a hint how to achieve this?
